# Php files not found on Apache server

Tags: php, apache, flask, http-status-code-404

I am developing a Flask app, and I have deployed it locally to an Apache server (it's my first time with Apache). It works ok, but now I would like to add the [PHPlitemyadmin](https://www.phpliteadmin.org/) php script in order to manager my sqlite database, but I can't seem to maki it work (I get Not Found).

I've been banging my head against the wall for the last hours. The site wiki says:

- Save and upload phpliteadmin.php to your web server.
- Open a web browser and navigate to the uploaded phpliteadmin.php file. You will be prompted to enter a password. Use the same password you set in step 4.

I copied the php script to `/path/to/webApp/directory/` but I can't navigate to it. In Apache's access.log I can see `"GET /phpliteadmin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 429 "` just after other correct gets in the same directory. Am I missing something? I also tried other php files, and none works, so maybe I should add something to Apache, despite the wiki not specifying anything about it. Ideally, I would like to access the script from `/admin`.

This is my `webApp.conf` in `sites-enabled`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ServerName <localIP>

     WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/webApp/directory/webApp.wsgi

     DocumentRoot /path/to/webApp/directory

     <Directory /path/to/webApp/directory>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     LogLevel warn

     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the following line to the site .conf:

```
Alias "/admin" "/path/to/webApp/directory/phpliteadmin.php"
```